# How to set HA LVM in RHEL 9 / Rocky Linux 9

Tags: linux, redhat, storage, lvm, cluster

I try to set HA LVM (active/passive) in Rocky Linux 9 for my cluster that have 2 nodes (node1 and node2).
I'm using iSCSI shared storage to set HA LVM in this cluster.
I set HA LVM with following detail bellow :

1. Create PV, VG, and LV on node1
2. Set "volume_list = [ root ]" for my local VG on each node
3. I try to set "locking_type" parameter in "/etc/lvm/lvm.conf", but parameter not found
4. Set initramfs by using command "dracut -fv" on each node
5. Reboot on each node

After reboot, VG only appear in node1, not in both.

I had try RHEL 9 documentation too like link information from link bellow, but problem still persist (VG not appear in node2) :

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_overview-of-high-availability-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters#con_HA-lvm-shared-volumes-overview-of-high-availability

Kindly need your help guys about this case. Thank you.